# Why my jquery code works in IE9 but not in IE8?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, fancybox

```
<script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#various2").fancybox({
                    'width': 800,
                    'height': 570,
                    'type':'iframe'
                });
            });
</script>
```

I'm getting error in IE8 and 7 but not in IE9

> Object doesn't support property or method 'fancybox'

and error is on this line

```
$("#various2").fancybox({
```

and my scripts are at bottom before `</body>`

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js" defer="defer"></script>
        <script>!window.jQuery && document.write(unescape('%3Cscript src="js/libs/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"%3E%3C/script%3E'))</script>
        <script src="js/plugins.js" defer="defer"></script>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#various2").fancybox({
                'width': 800,
                'height': 570,
                'type':'iframe'
            });
        });
        </script>
```

Comment: where does the fancybox script is located ? head ? body ?

Comment: make sure it's loaded after jQuery.

Comment: `<script src="//aja` missing `http:` maybe a typo, also try using `<script type="text/javascript">`

Comment: @3nigma - I don't think this is a typo - using this will allow the CDN to function from both http and https

Comment: @ScottE  ok tnx for enlightening me `:)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, you should debug around defer="defer" part. Different IE versions may be interpreting it different way, causing js libs to be parsed after body script gets parsed.

Comment: @JitendraVyas , if possible, you may help digg things a bit here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7729530/ie-iframe-widget-and-jquery-drag-and-drop-alignment-issue . Your profile seems strong with UI and browsers. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2):

You are using `defer` on the jQuery library, which means it is probably not getting loaded before the jQuery code itself.

Since your scripts are at the bottom of the page before `</body>` there is *no need to defer loading them at all* since the rest of the page had already loaded.

Comment: This is incorrect. Without `defer`, scripts will not start downloading until all previous scripts have completed downloading and executing. `defer` is almost always a good thing, even for scripts at the end of the `body`.

Comment: @mattbasta I was under the impression that everything downloads in parallel in modern browsers?

Answer (score 1):

Inline script tags don't support `defer`, and so will always execute as soon as they are encountered. Because your external script has `defer`, it will load at some arbitrary point in the future. Thus, your inline script will (almost) always execute before your external script has downloaded and run.